# Usability improvement for Data Explorer - option to substitute my user id

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer

[Many queries posted on Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta/queries) require a user ID, which I don't remember off top of my head (obviously). I suggest the following enhancement to Data Explorer:

[image]

So if you check the above check box, the user id will be pre-populated for you, showing user name in brackets (as a confirmation to be a valid ID).

Data Explorer already has a site selection, so it could use my logon information to pull out the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This already exists. From the [Data Explorer help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

> The `##UserId##` parameter is treated specially for users who are logged in. If they have an account on the target site that shares the email used in their Data Explorer account, their user ID on that site will be automatically populated.

Simply set your email address to match the target site account.

Comment: My email address is the same on all accounts. Yes, you are right, it indeed works like that. Would be nice to add some clue for new users. Maybe put user name in brackets, so that you will notice it's you there by default. Or to tell which other user you will be querying, just to double-check. Could be site icon + user name, to avoid confusion 100%. What confused me is that I was looking for an SO id, which is different from my meta ID.

Comment: Your user ID always differs between sites (unless you are Jeff Atwood, then you always get 1). Note that most people don't read the help (where this is documented quite early on), but I don't think showing your name behind it will necessarily make it any clearer.

Comment: Well, showing my user name beside it would tell me that it's not just **some user id**, being different from my SO id, it's in fact my id, but on meta (or another website). Then everything starts to make sense. My first impression is that query owner's user id is being shown by default. You cannot rely on people reading documentation these days.

Comment: @Neolisk: well, the DE code is Open Source, so you could [propose a patch](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer) if this is up your street.